# Python ggplot rotate axis labels

Tags: python, python-ggplot

when I tried to plot a timeseries with ggplot, the x axis lables became too crowded  and overlapped each other:

[image: screenshot1]

The code is:

```
plot = ggplot(df, aes(x=df.index, weight='COUNT')) + \
    geom_bar() + \
    xlab('Date') + \
    ylab('Incidents')
```

I tried to add the following line

```
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

to the plot, but it doesn't work. And this extra line gives me error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Any idea how this happened and how should I fix it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

(Old question, posting the answer if anyone comes across this in the future)

"axis.text.x" format is used for R. When using ggplot for python, replace "axis.text.x" with "axis_text_x"

This worked for me:

```
theme(axis_text_x  = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

---

**Reference:** https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/blob/master/ggplot/themes/theme.py

Comment: This rotates the tick labels for me, but it also changes them for integers from 0 to n, instead of the original labels.

Comment: Seriously. That whole change to integers thing makes this option a lot less functional. Anybody discover a workaround for this?

Comment: Converted the indices to integers. is there a way to map it back?